# incorrect value from glGetProgramiv(program, GL_ACTIVE_UNIFORM_MAX_LENGTH, outParam)

Tags: opengl, glsl

I need the maximum length of a uniform name. ie: given a used program with uniforms `uniform test` and `uniform myuniform`, `glGetProgramiv(program, GL_ACTIVE_UNIFORM_MAX_LENGTH, outParam)` should get output of 10 (for "myuniform").

I have a very simple test shader set up with 1 defined uniform: `uniform float time`

`glGetProgramiv(program, GL_ACTIVE_UNIFORM_MAX_LENGTH, outParam)` returns 5, the length of `time`. If I change "time" to something else, it returns the changed length (ex: change to "timer" it returns 6).

`glGetProgramiv` with `GL_ACTIVE_UNIFORMS` tells me that there are 2 uniforms. 
The second uniform that it is reporting is gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix.

I am fine with it including gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix in the list - I am using it in the shader, but this brings up a problem when combined with the other return value. Why doesn't glGetProgramiv return the length of "gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix" if it is including it in the list? I need the full names of attributes and variables for my application, but since I am getting a max length of 5, `glGetActiveUniform` is returning a uniform name of "gl_M" which is not acceptable.

Either the max name length should include the MVP matrix, or the list of names should not. It does not make sense to include the name in the list but not in the max name length calculation.

Is this happening only for me? I could not find anything else about it using Google. I could abandon a query for max length and always use very big buffers, but I've seen some very long variable names before, so the buffers would have to be huge to guarantee no errors. That's not a real fix anyway.

This test is working correctly for attributes. I use gl_Vertex and have no other attributes. The system reports 1 current attribute with a length of 10 and a name of gl_Vertex correctly. If I remove my time uniform entirely, that leaves the MVP matrix as the only used uniform, the system reports 1 current uniform, max name length of 0, so getting its name with the returned max length gets nothing.

For completeness, I include the code below. The code is in Java and uses JOGL to access OpenGL bindings. To highlight the relevant areas, I have deleted lines not relevant to this issue, which was mostly the GUI updating, including the GUI part that actually shows the values obtained in here. I also deleted the part that gets the attributes since that works fine, as stated above.

FYI for the C people who are wary of the Java-isms: think of a Buffer (`IntBuffer`, `ByteBuffer`, `FloatBuffer`) like a pointer, `buffer.get()` like `buffer[n++]`, and `buffer = IntBuffer.allocate(n)` like a `malloc()`. I also use OpenGL in C and C++, so I can rewrite this in C if the GLSL gurus here prefer that.

Any suggestions?

```
// add options to panelShaderParameters
public void updateShaderParameters(GLAutoDrawable surface)
{
    GL2 gl = surface.getGL().getGL2();

    IntBuffer outParam = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
    int numParameters = 0,
        maxNameLength = 0;

    IntBuffer size = null,
        type = null;
    ByteBuffer name = null;

    gl.glGetProgramiv(shader.getName(), GL2.GL_ACTIVE_UNIFORMS, outParam);
    numParameters = outParam.get();
    outParam = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
    gl.glGetProgramiv(shader.getName(), GL2.GL_ACTIVE_UNIFORM_MAX_LENGTH, outParam);
    maxNameLength = outParam.get();

    for(int i = 0; i < numParameters; i += 1)
    {
        size = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
        type = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
        name = ByteBuffer.allocate(maxNameLength);
        gl.glGetActiveUniform(shader.getName(), i, maxNameLength, (IntBuffer)null, size, type, name);
        byte[] nameBuffer = new byte[maxNameLength];
        name.position(0);
        name.get(nameBuffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: "*I could not find anything else about it using Google.*" That's because most people don't try to query uniform names. They *know* what their uniforms are called.

Comment: This application allows dynamic loading of models and shaders. The parameters are provided to the user with a means of editing the values. I have a section of the GUI that allows you to load any vertex and fragment shaders you want and apply them to the model you are currently viewing. So I cannot know all the uniform names.

Comment: I was simply telling you *why* you couldn't find much on Google about this. Most people don't write applications where they need to query uniform names. You do, so you got tripped up by a driver bug in disused API functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have found a driver bug. You can attempt to report it ([this forum is a place where it may be seen](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/forumdisplay.php/17-OpenGL-drivers)), but there's nothing you can do to make it work correctly. So just work around it.

Rather than having a single max-size, just ask each uniform in turn what it's length is. In C/C++, you do this by passing NULL for the buffer to [`glGetActiveUniformName`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGetActiveUniformName):

```
GLsizei length;
glGetActiveUniformName(program, index, 1000 /*large number*/, &length, NULL);
//Use length to allocate a buffer of the appropriate size.
```

I don't know how this would work using JOGL. Perhaps you should switch to LWJGL, which has a [much more reasonable Java implementation of this function.](http://www.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/GL31.html#glGetActiveUniformName%28int,%20int,%20int%29)

Also, stop storing the strings as byte arrays. Convert them into proper Java strings (another reason to use LWJGL).

Comment: I had not considered driver bug. I tested on another computer, and yes, you are correct. It performs the expected behavior there. Thank you. Also, thank you for that tip to find the size of a specific one by index, I don't think that was mentioned on the documentation I was looking at on khronos.org.

Comment: As for the recommendations to do some things different, unfortunately that is not an option here: my job requires JOGL, and JOGL supports only byte buffer forms of these methods, so I must get that then convert to string after, which I do elsewhere.

Comment: I just thought of another workaround as well: the shader code could be parsed and names could be extracted directly from that. However, since this is a driver bug, as you pointed out, I will not bother with that. Again, thank you.

Comment: @Loduwijk: "*However, since this is a driver bug, as you pointed out, I will leave it as-is for now with no workarounds.*" Why? This kind of driver bug would almost certainly be a low-priority fix. It won't be fixed for months, if *ever*. And the workaround is sanctioned by the spec, so it would actually work, and it's far less likely to succumb to driver bugs. There's no reason *not* to use the workaround.

Comment: My thought was that, if it's a driver bug, it would be an uncommon problem and that I just happened to be the rare exception that happened to encounter it. You are right though, it is simple enough to fix, especially with your suggestion, and if I encountered it as the developer, on the computer that I happened to be running it on at the time, I should not be so quick to assume it will work fine for everyone else. Good call, and thank you for your sage advice.

Answer (score 0):

We had exactly this problem, and I have seen it described here by other:

http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/179117-Driver-bug-causing-incorrect-glGetProgramiv-output

In my case, the problem arose after upgrading from nvidia 295.40 driver to 304.64, in various GPU models. In that forum above the bug was reported for an intel driver ¿ which driver are you using Ludowijk ?

I guess that perhaps builtin attributes starting with "gl_" are not considered for max name length computation, but even if this is true this behavoir should be considered a bug IMHO.

Thanks Nicol for the idea for the workaround.

Comment: Yes, that post that you linked to was my bug report I made, so it was describing my system. I am no longer using that computer, but if it would be useful I can get ahold of that computer again to get more information or for further tests.